# Merge 2 models in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to merge two Keras Sequential model. The aim is to get output from 1 model, run the output through a function and then use that as an input to another model. I don't even know whether such model is trainable or not.

The two models are given below

```
def feature_extractor():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), (2, 2), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), (2, 2), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), (2, 2), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), (2, 2), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'same'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  return model

def layer_flow_estimator():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'valid'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'valid'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'valid'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), (1, 1), 'valid'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.2))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(final_width*final_height*final_channels))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((final_width, final_height, final_channels)))
  return model
```

the function is as such

```
@tf.function
def cal_cost(features):
  cost = tf.zeros([6, 32, 56, 128])
  for i in range(6):  
    f_width, f_height, f_channels = tf.squeeze(features[i]).shape
    flat_feature1 = tf.reshape(features[i], [f_width*f_height*f_channels])
    flat_feature2 = tf.reshape(features[i+1], [f_width*f_height*f_channels])
    cost_vol = tfp.stats.correlation(flat_feature1, flat_feature2)   #normalize here ############################
    cost[i] = tf.reshape(cost_vol, [f_width, f_height, f_channels])
    print(i)
  inp = tf.zeros([6, 96, 56, 128])
  for i in range(6):
    inp[i] = tf.concat([features[i], features[i+1], cost[i]], axis=0)
  return inp
```

The flow should be as such - input -> feature_extractor -> cal_cost -> layer_flow_estimator -> output.
Please help

Comment: First, you cannot use numpy function in the training cycle. You need to either rewrite `cal_cost` using functions from the `tf` only, or use `@tf.function`, if possible.
Second, what you want can be fairly easy implemented using functional API. Consult [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#use_the_same_graph_of_layers_to_define_multiple_models) for details.

Comment: @Ivan K, can you elaborate more on how to write the cal_cost function. I tried it in a way but that did not work. Code edited with the new code. Please check once

Comment: Are you trying to achieve [`FlowNet`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06852) like architecture?

Comment: @M.Innat, like PWC-Net

Comment: like https://github.com/philferriere/tfoptflow